# Android Add task with checkbox and rating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I bought the Developing Android Applications with Java video lessons with the intention of learning about android.There is a tutorial where we learn how to add a task with a "checkbox" next to it so it ca be used to eliminated completed tasks.I want to know how to add a rating bar below the task so that the task itself be rated.I've tried different things but nothing worked.It is to much to paste the entire code so I will try to identify the relevant parts

The project has 3 graphical layouts(xml files).The first one for presenting the list of tasks ,the second one with the required buttons(add task,delete) and this one with the checkbox and hopefully with the rating bar also.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <project.android.taskmanager.views.TaskListItem 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <CheckedTextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" />
```

By doing this the rating bar appears on the graphical layout

```
 <RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:stepSize="0.1"/>
</project.android.taskmanager.views.TaskListItem>
```

Below the class that is used for the above xml file,since we have to interact with the checkbox.

```
     package project.android.taskmanager.views;
      import project.android.taskmanager.R;
      import project.android.taskmanager.tasks.Task;

      import android.content.Context;
      import android.util.AttributeSet;
      import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
      import android.widget.LinearLayout;
      import android.widget.RatingBar;
      import android.widget.RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener;
      import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


    public class TaskListItem extends RelativeLayout {

    private Task task;
    private CheckedTextView checkbox;
    private RatingBar ratingbar;




    public TaskListItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        checkbox = (CheckedTextView)findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        ratingbar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);


    }

    public void setTask(Task task) {
        this.task = task;
        checkbox.setText(task.getName());

        checkbox.setChecked(task.isComplete());

    }

    public Task getTask() {
        return task;
    }

}
```

Addingthe following didn't work.

```
final RatingBar ratingbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
        Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, "New Rating: " + rating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

What should I do in order to add a ratingbar along side with the checkbox so that the user can interact with it?

Comment: Is your *TaskListItem* inflated from an XML resource? What does that xml look like?

Comment: the TaskListItem class is only correlated with the above xml,in order to make the widgets interactable...hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how you have the whole thing set up, but you could put everything inside of a `RelativeLayout`, then assign the values to the checkbox:  `android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and say `android:id="@+id/checkbox"`.
Then on the rating bar assign the values: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkbox"`.

I don't know if this will work how you want to set it up, but from what I'm understanding of what you're trying to accomplish, this is how I would do it.